# Have more to do

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence from  “Principles.” Dalio, Ray.

> Whatever success I’ve had in life has had more to do with my knowing how to deal with my not knowing than anything I know.

It's a complicated structured sentence,
Does it mean that 'My success comes more from my knowing how to deal with my not knowing'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means his success owes more to him knowing how to deal with his ignorance (that is, his "not knowing") than to his knowledge of everything else.

**A** "has more to do" with *B* than *C* if **A** is more relevant to the issue in question (that is *B* here) than *C*.